# Create tree which displays multiple folder paths

Tags: php, jquery, html

I've got an multidimensional array with some folder paths. Out of this array I should build ONE tree. Similar to that when you use "tree" in the command prompt. Sorry for my bad English and my tiny knowledge I'm still a student.

Multidimensional array:

```
 Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [X:] => Array
            (
                [A1] => Array
                    (
                        [10_ColdForging] => Array
                            (
                                [01_Administration] => Array
                                    (
                                    )

                            )

                    )

            )

    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [X:] => Array
            (
                [A1] => Array
                    (
                        [99_MusterOrdner] => Array
                            (
                            )

                    )

            )

    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [X:] => Array
            (
                [A1] => Array
                    (
                        [10_ColdForging] => Array
                            (
                            )

                    )

            )

    )

)
```

The tree should look similar to this:

```
X:\
  A1
    10_ColdForging
            01_Administration
    99_MusterOrdner
```

I found some JavaScript stuff but they all want to list the entire directory. Something
[like this](http://forrst.com/posts/Awesome_PHP_RecursiveTreeIterator-O3R) would be perfect.
But I don't get how it works, there is no documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I solved the problem. I've changed the array so it looks like this:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => Y:
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => A1
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => 10_ColdForging
        [1] => 99_MusterOrdner
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [0] => 01_Administration
    )

)
```

Then I used the function from [here](http://phpflow.com/php/how-to-create-dynamic-tree-view-menu/) and it works. There is just a little problem, the sub folder isn't listed correct. It's listed in "99_MusterOrder", but it should be in "10_ColdForging". I'm gonna modify the array or the function to solve that.

**EDIT :**

Found a very good script which converts the array in that what i need:
[HERE](http://kvz.io/blog/2007/10/03/convert-anything-to-tree-structures-in-php/)

I combined it with the script above and it is working like a charm.

```
Array
(
[Y:] => Array
    (
        [A1] => Array
            (
                [10_ColdForging] => Array
                    (
                        [02_Travel] => X:\A1\10_ColdForging\02_Travel
                        [01_Administration] => X:\A1\10_ColdForging\01_Administration
                    )

                [99_MusterOrdner] => X:\A1\99_MusterOrdner
            )

        [A3] => Array
            (
                [02_department] => Array
                    (
                        [001_Coaches] => X:\A3\02_department\001_Coaches
                    )

            )

    )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: (Taken from the link you posted and edited).

```
<?php

$hey = array(
    'X:\\',
    array(
        'A1',
        array('10_coldForgin', array('01_Administration'), '99_MusterOrdner')
    )
);

$awesome = new RecursiveTreeIterator(
    new RecursiveArrayIterator($hey), 
    null, null, RecursiveIteratorIterator::LEAVES_ONLY
);

foreach ($awesome as $line) 
    echo $line.PHP_EOL;
```

It looked like this for me:

```
|-X:\
  |-A1
    |-10_coldForgin
    | \-01_Administration
    \-99_MusterOrdner
```

Comment: strange for me it looks different. It's all in one row. The Second Problem is that all the data are dynamic. So i cant hardcode anything. Maybe some tips how i could clean up the array so that it's structured like in your example?

Comment: Any idea if i could use this for my array, or modify my array that it works? http://phpflow.com/php/how-to-create-dynamic-tree-view-menu/